# Specify NullConstraint on Entity Table using eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

To specify a UniqueConstraint on multiple columns, i use the @Table annotation and specify the value for uniqueConstraint.
I would also like to add a null constraint based on this scenario:

```
@Entity
public class Contact{
  private PhoneBook phoneBook;
  private ContactGroup group;
}
```

An entity can either be in a phoneBook, or in a group but not both, since a group already has a reference to phonebook it belongs to. In this case, both phonebook and group must both not be null and must both not be set, only one can be set at a time.

Working on netbeans 7.2, glassfish 3.2 eclipselink 2.0

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think you can do this in JPA. To get around this in the past I have checked this in the business logic and also added check constraint to my DB so that they cannot both be set

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Contact{

  @NotNull
  private PhoneBook phoneBook;

  @NotNull
  private ContactGroup group;
}
```

Should work :)

EDIT:

I'm sorry, now I see you writing about cross validation, probably you have to write your own validator.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply throw `ConstraintViolationException` in the setter of `phoneBook` or `group` depending on the condition.